# WPF window_loaded exception in my first WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am learning WPF and its my first MVVM application. I am seeing a video where the MVVM is demonstrated using Silverlight app. However, I am mimicking it for WPF. in Silverlight, the video presenter creates an event in UserControl XAML tag namely UserControl_Loaded which is successful.

However, I am creating a Window_Loaded in Window root element of xaml file of MainWindow.xaml

I am getting this error :( Please help me. This event "Window_Loaded" is in this 5th line only.

Exception:

> 'Add value to collection of type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' threw an exception.'
>   Line number '5' and line position '28'.
>
> Inner Exception:
>
> {"Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of
>   Visual."}

Please also explain me why it is happening along with the solution. I am just trying to learn MVVM and using observable collection, INotifyPropertyChanged and a model class and I am generating data of this object in hardcoded way.

Note:

I suspect it is due to clr-namespace.

First, I am wondering, why if I type clr, intellisense is not taking me to clr ? Rather it just takes me to first http in the sequence of list of namespaces. Second, the Silverlight Video used the namespace of the project, however, I used the namespace of the View. Because, when I use the namespace of the project, it gives me error saying "view" is not found. Anywhere I am going wrong :(

### (OR):

Is it due to a new Window.xaml page that I am trying to insert into another window.xaml page ? Unlike the Silverlight video where it does insert a UserControl into a Page.

MainWindow into MainWindow is a problem here ?
If I use UserControl into MainWindow will it be resolved ? Meaning tha, we cnn't have window into window ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, when I used "UserControl.xaml" in View instead of a "Window.xaml"it worked to my surprise. But how and why ? Generally View Folder should have Window.xaml windows right in WPF for various screens ? Not only User Controls. Why it throws error in earlier case :(

Answer (score 4):

You can not have a Window inside another Window! Window should be the root element of your xaml, and you can add other elements inside it. For example Grid. My suggestion is to find some WPF tutorials and books (not silverlight), for starting, because WPF is much more powerfull, and in many ways different.

Comment: Hi Vale, thank you so much. I am beginner to this. But I have a doubt Vale. In the MVVM Project structure, under the View folder, we will be having all UserControl.xaml only ? And Not Window.Xaml ? Like you see, when I compare to Winforms, we add so many winforms for different screens under the "View" Folder in MVP. So, it means, in MVVM, View Folder doesn't contain different windows at all :0 Its a big shock to me if it is like this.

Comment: You can have many user controls, and also many windows. I think you are confused by Silverlight. There is not Window in Silverlight! Because it is designed as plug-in, so window is actually the web page. Get some WPF book, and leave Silverlight alone, unless you want to do web programming. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks Vale. I don't want to go to Silverlight now. I have a WPF interview tomorrow :( I am just starting it :P Ok I will study some good book on WPF. Do you have any suggestion for beginner of WPF ? Preferably, I need layman explanations as well as , it should enforce MVVM style. I am accustomed to using blend, wpf to some extent though few years back, but now I am again coming back to WPF.

Comment: Also, if you can point me to good video tutorials and a good WPF E-book link, it will be great. Also, which version of WPF is currently in use ? WPF 4 ?

Comment: I used "Pro WPF in C# 2010" by Matthew MacDonald. It is for .NET 4. It does not cover MVVM, you will have to google that yourself. There is .NET 4.5 now, but the difference is not big in WPF framework. For tutorials, google specific question. You need to research a lot by yourself if you want to learn and work with WPF.

Comment: Hi Vale, sure I will do my work to get some tutorials. Especially I forsee important topics like, command, navigation, data binding, dependency property, styles and resources etc on my interview. Let me quickly get good links and knowledge on that. Thats why I am practising whatever I see in videos myself to be confident :) Thank you for the book suggestion, I will try to download it or buy it in hardcopy. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Window.xaml:

```
<Window  x:Class="WpfMvvmApplication1.Views.Login"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:View="clr-namespace:WpfMvvmApplication1.Views">
<Grid>
   <View:UserControl/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

This will import your usercontrol into window./

Hope this will help you.